# How can I make an animated gif appear when the site is loading and disappear after it's done loading?

Tags: jquery-plugins, throbber

I've been using the plugin in here: http://contextllc.com/tools/jQuery-showLoading which works perfectly when it's an ajax request or any other element interaction but how to get the animation appear when the site is first loading and have it disappear after it finishes loading?

Comment: FYI: The link mentioned is broken, at least at the moment, and I do not see a version post 1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascripts onLoad event to show the animation and jquery .ready()-function to remove it. [More about onload event](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onload.asp) and [more about .ready()-function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: I tried that but it loads AFTER everything gets loaded (or at least after the PHP loads which is what I want to indicate that is loading)

Comment: You could try that you echo the animation-code first in php code. And when the DOM is ready remove animation in .ready()-function.